# DOMException: Failed to load because no supported source was found - Playpromise rejected

Tags: google-chrome, autoplay

Facing a strange issue, having an application with 350+ MCQ's question with audio which play automatically on each question and it works perfectly for 261 questions but instantly i got a message about DOMException. Working perfectly on Firefox all questions with audio but in Chrome it is not working. Tried with other audio files but everytime after 261 questions. Even i deleted 261 question but all in vain.

[image]